# Benefits of using C# .NET for web developmet

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc

my question might sound stupid to some of you, but I need  some good answers here. I have experience working with PHP and Ruby on Rails. I know what are the benefits in using both technologies, (MVC, performance and etc). Now I am working on a project written in C#. Based on what I have seen so far, the browser code is a mixture of HTML, inline and external CSS, and I some C# methods to generate HTML content. Everything is so messy, I have been working on it for 3days and I am still confused.From that C# implementation, there is not well structured MVC. My impression is that C# does not seem like a good choice when it comes to web app (for me). Maybe the code I am working with is written in a wrong way. My question is, is the messy HTML/CSS and the lack of MVC implementation something common when it comes to C# ? What are the benefits of C# over PHP, Java and ROR for developing small and big web applications.

Exaple from the code I work with:

```
</td>
    <td align="left">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txt_to" runat="server" Enabled="true" 
                    TextAlignment="Center" MaxLength="7000"
                    AcceptsReturn="True"  ToolTip="Add ; after a recepient to add another recepient" 
                    CssClass="txt_Message1" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txt_to" MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
                    CompletionInterval="10" CompletionSetCount="3"
                    EnableCaching="true" FirstRowSelected="true" 
                    UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
                    DelimiterCharacters=";, :"  howOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true" /> 

       <asp:Label ID="lbl_ToError" runat="server" CssClass="Error"></asp:Label>
    </td>
```

This look too much complicated for me, at the end of the day it is just a text field :) And another thing, most of my global Css gets overloaded by the inline values ( I believe they are generated using some sort of a generator or VS tool).

Please, dont get offended, I have no experience with C# .NET this is my first contact and my impression is "Never ever". I hope it is the code I am working with, not the C#. Give me explanation why I should use C#? So far it has been a pain for me :)

Comment: I don't speak C#, but what you are showing is *way* more than a text field, no? And you're completely overlooking what features the above code brings *out of the box* (like validation) that you would have to painstakingly add in PHP (leading to more code.)

Comment: Not really sure this question makes sense for SO. This is a subjective discussion about ASP.NET (not C#) as compared to other web-oriented languages.

Comment: For me this question is just about impossible to answer - C# works for some and not for others. It depends on the experience of the developer and requirements of the project Yes, that is just a textbox - but one with a CSS class, tooltip, width, max length and enabled properties set. Setting a lot of properties will generally mean writing a lot of code.

Comment: Subjective is the word I was looking for, thanks @jwiscarson !

Comment: I agree that ASP.NET's controls can be a bit much, although I don't think the code you've shown is *that* hard to follow.  ASP.NET MVC is a giant step in the right direction IMO, especially when used with Razor.  No matter what language/frameworks you use, it's up to the programmer to write good code.  Although you'll always find yourself working on a project that looks like it was written by interns ;p  Damn them!

Comment: You example is not really related to C#... It's really a questions of asp.net web forms and it server-side programming better or worse than something else (such as MVC). What you call messy might make sense to someone who embraces the server-side approach. I don't think you'll find your answer here on stack. As a .net dev, I can tell you that I had similar frustrations moving from web forms to things like ruby on rails, or objective-c. As you change stacks, you'll need to understand new philosophies. You might now always agree with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). Seems like it would fit your requirements more :)